# CodeIgniter controller only respond to browser

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter project set up in gcloud and i written a simple post and get controller like this:

```
public function test2() {
    echo "hello"
}
public function test() {
    $input_data = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input')), true);
    print_r($input_data);   
}
```

As you get test it here

- https://rbm2018-123.appspot.com/api/member/test
- https://rbm2018-123.appspot.com/api/member/test2

it seems that i get a response from /test when i call it in the browser, but when it comes to calling via postman or CURL it doesnt work!

So i CURL test against localhost and server using this code

```
<?php 
post();
echo "<hr>";
get();
function post() {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $url1 = 'https://rbm2018-123.appspot.com/api/member/test';
    $url2 = 'localhost/nrb-website/api/member/test';
    $payload = `{
                    "qwerty": 1234,
                    "comeon": "sdgsdkjsdfsdgf"
                }`;
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url2,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type:application/json'),
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $payload
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    print_r($result);
}

function get() {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $url1 = 'https://rbm2018-123.appspot.com/api/member/test2';
    $url2 = 'localhost/nrb-website/api/member/test2';
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url2,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request'
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    print_r($result);   
}
?>
```

CURL post for url1 and url2 doesn't respond with any result
CURL get for url2 responded with a result but url2 didnt.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like CodeIgniter blocks the "file_get_contents('php://input')"-request, check out this https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#using-the-php-input-stream.

Also check your PHP Errors they can help alot, I use the most time display_errors=true on my dev servers.

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

I found out, i need to add

```
google_app_engine.enable_curl_lite = "1"
```

to php.ini in the root of my app to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Note : you missed to add http:// in url2 check it